# CS2066 Cannot implictly convert type 'OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.Chromedriver' to 'OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver'. An explicit conversion exists

Tags: c#, selenium

I am totally new to automation and new to Specflow and trying to follow an online course, but I get this error and I am unable as of yet to resolve. I have tried looking on the internet but I do not follow how to apply the information to get rid of the error in my script. I have restarted my laptop and the class and I checked the nugget to see that Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver' has installed. There is a course tutor but he has not responded to a query I raised 2x days ago. So I thought I would try online forums such as this, as it helps to get timely feedback.

Here is the code, any help resolving this is appreciated. Thanks.

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;

namespace UdemyTestProjectJK1.Utilities
{
    [Binding]
    public class Hooks1
    {

        public static IWebDriver driver;
        

        [BeforeScenario]
        public void BeforeScenario()
        {
            driver = new Chromedriver();
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        }

        [AfterScenario]
        public void AfterScenario()
        {
            driver.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this line in your code :

```
driver = new Chromedriver();
```

do this :

```
   driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\my\path\to\chromedriver\directory");
```

and download chromdriver from [here](https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/) and put it above with full path.

or

if Install `Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver` from NuGet and then you can do the following:

```
driver = new ChromeDriver(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
```